# How to read data of an Excel file using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

How to read an Excel file using C#?  I open an Excel file for reading and copy it to clipboard to search email format, but I don't know how to do it.

```
FileInfo finfo;
Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelObj = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
ExcelObj.Visible = false;

Excel.Workbook theWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet worksheet;

if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem s in listView1.Items)
    {
        finfo = new FileInfo(s.Text);
        if (finfo.Extension == ".xls" || finfo.Extension == ".xlsx" || finfo.Extension == ".xlt" || finfo.Extension == ".xlsm" || finfo.Extension == ".csv")
        {
            theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(s.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, false, false);

            for (int count = 1; count <= theWorkbook.Sheets.Count; count++)
            {
                worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)theWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(count);
                worksheet.Activate();
                worksheet.Visible = false;
                worksheet.UsedRange.Cells.Select();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: New users coming for a solution might want to see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302235/how-to-read-from-xlsx-excel).

Answer (score 94):

OK,

One of the more difficult concepts to grasp about Excel VSTO programming is that you don't refer to cells like an array, `Worksheet[0][0]` won't give you cell A1, it will error out on you.  Even when you type into A1 when Excel is open, you are actually entering data into Range A1.  Therefore you refer to cells as Named Ranges.  Here's an example:

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"] as Excel.Worksheet; 
Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value)
```

You can now literally type:

```
range.Text // this will give you the text the user sees
range.Value2 // this will give you the actual value stored by Excel (without rounding)
```

If you want to do something like this:

```
Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1:A5", Missing.Value)

if (range1 != null)
     foreach (Excel.Range r in range1)
     {
         string user = r.Text
         string value = r.Value2

     }
```

There might be a better way, but this has worked for me.

The reason you need to use `Value2` and not `Value` is because the `Value` property is a parametrized and C# doesn't support them yet.

As for the cleanup code, i will post that when i get to work tomorrow, i don't have the code with me, but it's very boilerplate.  You just close and release the objects in the reverse order you created them.  You can't use a `Using()` block because the Excel.Application or Excel.Workbook doesn't implement `IDisposable`, and if you don't clean-up, you will be left with a hanging Excel objects in memory.

Note:

- If you don't set the `Visibility` property Excel doesn't display, which can be disconcerting to your users, but if you want to just rip the data out, that is probably good enough
- You could OleDb, that will work too.

I hope that gets you started, let me know if you need further clarification.  I'll post a complete

here is a complete sample:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ExcelTools = Ms.Office;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ExcelSingle
    {
        [Test]
        public void ProcessWorkbook()
        {
            string file = @"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\TestSheet.xls";
            Console.WriteLine(file);

            Excel.Application excel = null;
            Excel.Workbook wkb = null;

            try
            {
                excel = new Excel.Application();

                wkb = ExcelTools.OfficeUtil.OpenBook(excel, file);

                Excel.Worksheet sheet = wkb.Sheets["Data"] as Excel.Worksheet;

                Excel.Range range = null;

                if (sheet != null)
                    range = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);

                string A1 = String.Empty;

                if( range != null )
                    A1 = range.Text.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("A1 value: {0}", A1);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //if you need to handle stuff
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (wkb != null)
                    ExcelTools.OfficeUtil.ReleaseRCM(wkb);

                if (excel != null)
                    ExcelTools.OfficeUtil.ReleaseRCM(excel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll post the functions from ExcelTools tomorrow, I don't have that code with me either.

Edit:
As promised, here are the Functions from ExcelTools you might need.

```
public static Excel.Workbook OpenBook(Excel.Application excelInstance, string fileName, bool readOnly, bool editable,
        bool updateLinks) {
        Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
            fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        return book;
    }

public static void ReleaseRCM(object o) {
        try {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
        } catch {
        } finally {
            o = null;
        }
    }
```

To be frank, this stuff is much easier if you use VB.NET.  It's in C# because I didn't write it.  VB.NET does option parameters well, C# does not, hence the Type.Missing.  Once you typed Type.Missing twice in a row, you run screaming from the room!

As for you question, you can try to following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find(VS.80).aspx

I will post an example when I get back from my meeting... cheers

Edit:  Here is an example

```
range = sheet.Cells.Find("Value to Find",
                                                 Type.Missing,
                                                 Type.Missing,
                                                 Type.Missing,
                                                 Type.Missing,
                                                 Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                                                 Type.Missing,
                                                 Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

range.Text; //give you the value found
```

Here is another example inspired by this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find(VS.80).aspx):

```
 range = sheet.Cells.Find("Value to find", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,false, false, Type.Missing);
```

It helps to understand the parameters.

P.S.  I'm one of those weird people who enjoys learning COM automation.  All this code steamed from a tool I wrote for work which required me to process over 1000+ spreadsheets from the lab each Monday.

Comment: i want to read excel file from Listview to search email id from excel file.... i am trying to do this...but i dont know the type of encoding of excel i mean dataformates... how can i read a excel file to search email id...i dont want to use data connection

Comment: +1 excellent in depth answer. just lost all the name/date of 400+ xls files out of a recovered hdd, and this got me right back on track in an hr

Comment: why the declaration line "using ExcelTools = Ms.Office;" saying "The type or namespace name 'Ms' could not be found" ?

Comment: @Rishi the Ms.Office namespace is nothing special.  It consists of a class with static methods that wraps the Open, Save, Add methods of the Interop Libraries to provide common overloads and to hide some of the Type.Missing and Missing.Value parameters required by the COM Interop Library.  If you'd like me to post the code, I can

Comment: `"VB.NET does option parameters well, C# does not, hence the Type.Missing."` Actually I think C# also handles optional parameters quite well since C# 4. See here for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2009/06/16/com-interop-in-c-4-0.aspx

Comment: Hi Chris, Do you happen to have the functions you wrote for Excel with you handy? Ms.ExcelTOols above? It will be very helpful for me if you could share

Answer (score 23):

You can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly to process excel files.

1. Right click on your project and go to `Add reference`. Add the
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly.
2. Include `using
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` to make use of assembly.

Here is the sample code:

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    //create the Application object we can use in the member functions.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    _excelApp.Visible = true;

    string fileName = "C:\\sampleExcelFile.xlsx";

    //open the workbook
    Workbook workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    //select the first sheet        
    Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

    //find the used range in worksheet
    Range excelRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

    //get an object array of all of the cells in the worksheet (their values)
    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
                XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

    //access the cells
    for (int row = 1;  row <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; ++col)
        {
            //access each cell
            Debug.Print(valueArray[row, col].ToString());
        }
    }

    //clean up stuffs
    workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

    _excelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excelApp);
```

Comment: I found that following COM objects need to be declared and then `ReleaseComObject()`ed during `clean up stuffs` or else I have a zombie excel exe running after code completion: The `Workbooks` object created on `_excelApp.Workbooks`, the `Worksheets` object created on `workbook.Worksheets`, `Range` objects created on `worksheet.UsedRange.Rows` and `worksheet.UsedRange.Columns`, and the `excelRange` object. Also I think replace the two `worksheet.UsedRange` usages with `excelRange` variable in case more COM objects are created from not using the existing variable.

Answer (score 17):

Why don't you create OleDbConnection? There are a lot of available resources in the Internet. Here is an example

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+filename+";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
con.Open();
try
{
     //Create Dataset and fill with imformation from the Excel Spreadsheet for easier reference
     DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
     OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT * FROM ["+listname+"$]" , con);
     myCommand.Fill(myDataSet);
     con.Close();
     richTextBox1.AppendText("\nDataSet Filled");

     //Travers through each row in the dataset
     foreach (DataRow myDataRow in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
     {
          //Stores info in Datarow into an array
          Object[] cells = myDataRow.ItemArray;
          //Traverse through each array and put into object cellContent as type Object
          //Using Object as for some reason the Dataset reads some blank value which
          //causes a hissy fit when trying to read. By using object I can convert to
          //String at a later point.
          foreach (object cellContent in cells)
          {
               //Convert object cellContect into String to read whilst replacing Line Breaks with a defined character
               string cellText = cellContent.ToString();
               cellText = cellText.Replace("\n", "|");
               //Read the string and put into Array of characters chars
               richTextBox1.AppendText("\n"+cellText);
          }
     }
     //Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     //Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
finally
{
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: One issue I've had with OleDbConnection (using the Oracle Data Adapter) was with a column that contained both numbers and text. I got a DataTable with the column formatted as number which was missing all the cells where the data was formatted as text. My solution was to use interop to convert the entire used range of the column to the TEXT format before using OleDBC to get the data.

Comment: Last working archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731065653/http://blog.brezovsky.net/en-text-38.html). Only 40 lines.. probably can just edit the post and add them in. *shrug*

Answer (score 9):

```
try
        {
            DataTable sheet1 = new DataTable("Excel Sheet");
            OleDbConnectionStringBuilder csbuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
            csbuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            csbuilder.DataSource = fileLocation;
            csbuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES");
            string selectSql = @"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(csbuilder.ConnectionString))
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectSql, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(sheet1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

This worked for me. Please try it and let me know for queries.

Comment: Your code works perfect for me, without install any libraries or another histories, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here's a 2020 answer - if you don't need to support the older .xls format (so pre 2003) you could use either:

- [LightweightExcelReader](https://github.com/ChrisHodges/LightweightExcelReader) to access specfic cells, or cursor through all the data in a spreadsheet.

or

- [ExcelToEnumerable](https://github.com/ChrisHodges/ExcelToEnumerable) if you want to map spreadsheet data to a list of objects.

Pros :

- **Performance** - at the time of writing (the the fastest way to read an .xlsx file)[https://github.com/ChrisHodges/ExcelToEnumerable#performance].
- **Simplicity** - less verbose than [OLE DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB) or [OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

Cons:

- Neither **LightweightExcelReader** nor **ExcelToEnumerable** support .xls files.

*Disclaimer:* I am the author of LightweightExcelReader and ExcelToEnumerable

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's important to know what you mean by "open an Excel file for reading and copy it to clipboard..."

This is very important because there are many ways you could do that depending just on what you intend to do. Let me explain:

1. If you want to read a set of data and copy that in the clipboard and you know the data format (e.g. column names), I suggest you use an **OleDbConnection** to open the file, this way you can treat the xls file content as a Database Table, so you can read data with SQL instruction and treat the data as you want.
2. If you want to do operations on the data with the Excel object model then open it in the way you began.
3. Some time it's possible to treat an xls file as a kind of csv file, there are tools like [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) which permit you to treat and open an xls file in a simple way by mapping a structure on an arbitrary object.

Another important point is in which Excel version the file is.

I have, unfortunately I say, a strong experience working with Office automation in all ways, even if bounded in concepts like Application Automation, Data Management and Plugins, and generally I suggest only as the last resort, to using Excel automation or Office automation to read data; just if there aren't better ways to accomplish that task.

Working with automation could be heavy in performance, in terms of resource cost, could involve in other issues related for example to security and more, and last but not at least, working with COM interop it's not so "free"..
So my suggestion is think and analyze the situation within your needs and then take the better way.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Open XML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/).

Here is some code to process a spreadsheet with a specific tab or sheet name and dump it to something like CSV.  (I chose a pipe instead of comma).

I wish it was easier to get the value from a cell, but I think this is what we are stuck with.  You can see that I reference the MSDN documents where I got most of this code.  That is what Microsoft recommends.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Got code from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx
    /// </summary>
    [Test]
    public void WriteOutExcelFile()
    {
        var fileName = "ExcelFiles\\File_With_Many_Tabs.xlsx";
        var sheetName = "Submission Form"; // Existing tab name.
        using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, isEditable: false))
        {
            var workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
            var sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
            var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)(workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id));
            var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

            foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
                foreach (var cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    Console.Write("|" + GetCellValue(cell, workbookPart));
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Got code from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cell"></param>
    /// <param name="workbookPart"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string GetCellValue(Cell cell, WorkbookPart workbookPart)
    {
        if (cell == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var value = cell.CellFormula != null
            ? cell.CellValue.InnerText 
            : cell.InnerText.Trim();

        // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
        // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
        // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
        // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
        // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
        // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
        // the words TRUE or FALSE.
        if (cell.DataType == null)
        {
            return value;
        }
        switch (cell.DataType.Value)
        {
            case CellValues.SharedString:

                // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                // shared strings table.
                var stringTable =
                    workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                // the table.
                if (stringTable != null)
                {
                    value =
                        stringTable.SharedStringTable
                            .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                }
                break;

            case CellValues.Boolean:
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "0":
                        value = "FALSE";
                        break;
                    default:
                        value = "TRUE";
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use OLEDB Connection to communicate with excel files. it gives better result

```
using System.Data.OleDb;



                string physicalPath = "Your Excel file physical path";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                String strNewPath = physicalPath;
                String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                String query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"; // You can use any different queries to get the data from the excel sheet
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);

                }
                catch
                {
                    // Exception Msg 

                }
                finally
                {
                    da.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }
```

The Output data will be stored in dataset, using the dataset object you can easily access the datas.
Hope this may helpful

Answer (score 1):

Using OlebDB, we can read excel file in C#, easily, here is the code while working with Web-Form, where FileUpload1 is file uploading tool

```
   string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
  if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
//get file path
filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
//get file extenstion
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
//save file on "Uploads" folder of project
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);

string conString = string.Empty;
//check file extension
switch (extension)
{
    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.
        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Excel03ConString;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
        break;
    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Excel07ConString;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
        break;
}

//create datatable object
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

//Use OldDb to read excel
using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

            //Get the name of First Sheet.
            connExcel.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            connExcel.Close();

            //Read Data from First Sheet.
            connExcel.Open();
            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
            odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
            odaExcel.Fill(dt);
            connExcel.Close();
        }
    }
}

//bind datatable with GridView
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Source : https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/read-excel-file-and-import-data-into-gridview-using-datatabl/209

Console application similar code example
https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/read-excel-file-in-c-console-application-example-using-oledb/168

If you need don't want to use OleDB, you can try https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader
 which seems to have the ability to handle both formats (.xls and .xslx)

Answer (score 0):

> Excel File Reader & Writer Without Excel On u'r System

- Download and add the dll for 
  [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/releases) u'r project.
- Using this code to read a excel file.

  ```
          using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
          {
             XSSFWorkbook XSSFWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
          }
          ISheet objxlWorkSheet = XSSFWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
          int intRowCount = 1;
          int intColumnCount = 0;
          for (; ; )
          {
              IRow Row = objxlWorkSheet.GetRow(intRowCount);
              if (Row != null)
              {
                  ICell Cell = Row.GetCell(0);
                  ICell objCell = objxlWorkSheet.GetRow(intRowCount).GetCell(intColumnCount); }}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExcelDataReader` see [GitHub](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

You need to install nugets :

-[ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/)

-[ExcelDataReader.DataSet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader.DataSet/3.7.0-develop00310)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using ExcelDataReader;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Excel parsing in this class is performed by using a common shareware Lib found on:
/// https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader
/// </summary>
public static class ExcelParser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load, read and get values from Excel sheet
    /// </summary>
    public static List<FileRow> GetExcelRows(string path, string sheetName, bool skipFirstLine)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return GetValues(path, sheetName, skipFirstLine);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("The process cannot access the file");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parse sheet names from given Excel file.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<string> GetSheetNames(string path)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

            using (var excelReader = GetExcelDataReader(path, stream))
            {
                var dataset = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                    {
                        UseHeaderRow = true
                    }
                });

                var names = from DataTable table in dataset.Tables
                            select table.TableName;

                return names.ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parse values from Excel sheet and add to Rows collection.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<FileRow> GetValues(string path, string sheetName, bool skipFirstLine)
    {
        var rowItems = new List<FileRow>();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (var excelReader = GetExcelDataReader(path, stream))
            {
                var dataset = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                    {
                        UseHeaderRow = skipFirstLine
                    }
                });


                foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[sheetName].Rows)
                {
                    var rowItem = new FileRow();
                    foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
                        rowItem.Values.Add(value);
                    rowItems.Add(rowItem);
                }
            }
        }
        return rowItems;
    }

    private static IExcelDataReader GetExcelDataReader(string path, Stream stream)
    {
        var extension = GetExtension(path);
        switch (extension)
        {
            case "xls":
                return ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            case "xlsx":
                return ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            default:
                throw new Exception(string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid Excel extension", extension));
        }
    }

    private static string GetExtension(string path)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        return extension == null ? null : extension.ToLower().Substring(1);
    }
}
```

With this entity :

```
public class FileRow
{
    public List<object> Values { get; set; }

    public FileRow()
    {
        Values = new List<object>();
    }
}
```

Use like that :

```
var txtPath = @"D:\Path\excelfile.xlsx";
var sheetNames = ExcelParser.GetSheetNames(txtPath);
var datas = ExcelParser.GetExcelRows(txtPath, sheetNames[0], true);
```

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way to read Excel files on server side app is Open XML.

Sharing few links -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478410.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc823095.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
public void excelRead(string sheetName)
        {
            Excel.Application appExl = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
            try
            {
                string methodName = "";


                Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
                Excel.Range ShtRange;

                //Opening Excel file(myData.xlsx)
                appExl = new Excel.Application();


                workbook = appExl.Workbooks.Open(sheetName, Missing.Value, ReadOnly: false);
                NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
                ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange; //gives the used cells in sheet


                int rCnt1 = 0;
                int cCnt1 = 0;

                for (rCnt1 = 1; rCnt1 <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; rCnt1++)
                {
                    for (cCnt1 = 1; cCnt1 <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; cCnt1++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToString(NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1].Value2) == "Y")
                        {

                            methodName = NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 - 2].Value2;
                            Type metdType = this.GetType();
                            MethodInfo mthInfo = metdType.GetMethod(methodName);

                            if (Convert.ToString(NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 - 2].Value2) == "fn_AddNum" || Convert.ToString(NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 - 2].Value2) == "fn_SubNum")
                            {
                                StaticVariable.intParam1 = Convert.ToInt32(NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 + 3].Value2);
                                StaticVariable.intParam2 = Convert.ToInt32(NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 + 4].Value2);
                                object[] mParam1 = new object[] { StaticVariable.intParam1, StaticVariable.intParam2 };
                                object result = mthInfo.Invoke(this, mParam1);
                                StaticVariable.intOutParam1 = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                                NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 + 5].Value2 = Convert.ToString(StaticVariable.intOutParam1) != "" ? Convert.ToString(StaticVariable.intOutParam1) : String.Empty;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                object[] mParam = new object[] { };
                                mthInfo.Invoke(this, mParam);

                                NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 + 5].Value2 = StaticVariable.outParam1 != "" ? StaticVariable.outParam1 : String.Empty;
                                NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 + 6].Value2 = StaticVariable.outParam2 != "" ? StaticVariable.outParam2 : String.Empty;
                            }
                            NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 + 1].Value2 = StaticVariable.resultOut;
                            NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1 + 2].Value2 = StaticVariable.resultDescription;
                        }

                        else if (Convert.ToString(NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1].Value2) == "N")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Result is No");
                        }
                        else if (Convert.ToString(NwSheet.Cells[rCnt1, cCnt1].Value2) == "EOF")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("End of File");
                        }

                    }
                }

                workbook.Save();
                workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                appExl.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ShtRange);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(NwSheet);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(appExl);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext();
            }
        }

//code for reading excel data in datatable
public void testExcel(string sheetName)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sheetName);

                foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL"))
                {
                    p.Kill();
                }
                //string fileName = "E:\\inputSheet";
                Excel.Application oXL;
                Workbook oWB;
                Worksheet oSheet;
                Range oRng;


                //  creat a Application object
                oXL = new Excel.Application();




                //   get   WorkBook  object
                oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(sheetName);


                //   get   WorkSheet object
                oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                //ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                DataRow dr;


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int jValue = oSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Columns.Count;
                int iValue = oSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Rows.Count;


                //  get data columns
                for (int j = 1; j <= jValue; j++)
                {
                    oRng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[1, j];
                    string strValue = oRng.Text.ToString();
                    dt.Columns.Add(strValue, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                }


                //string colString = sb.ToString().Trim();
                //string[] colArray = colString.Split(':');


                //  get data in cell
                for (int i = 2; i <= iValue; i++)
                {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int j = 1; j <= jValue; j++)
                    {
                        oRng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[i, j];
                        string strValue = oRng.Text.ToString();
                        dr[j - 1] = strValue;


                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                if(StaticVariable.dtExcel != null)
                {
                    StaticVariable.dtExcel.Clear();
                    StaticVariable.dtExcel = dt.Copy();
                }
                else
                StaticVariable.dtExcel = dt.Copy();

                oWB.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                oXL.Quit();
                MessageBox.Show(sheetName);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

//code for class initialize
 public static void startTesting(TestContext context)
        {

            Playback.Initialize();
            ReadExcel myClassObj = new ReadExcel();
            string sheetName="";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"E:\SaveSheetName.txt");
            sheetName = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            myClassObj.excelRead(sheetName);
            myClassObj.testExcel(sheetName);
        }

//code for test initalize
public  void runValidatonTest()
        {

            DataTable dtFinal = StaticVariable.dtExcel.Copy();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtFinal.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (TestContext.TestName == dtFinal.Rows[i][2].ToString() && dtFinal.Rows[i][3].ToString() == "Y" && dtFinal.Rows[i][4].ToString() == "TRUE")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(TestContext.TestName);
                    MessageBox.Show(dtFinal.Rows[i][2].ToString());
                    StaticVariable.runValidateResult = "true";
                    break;
                }
            }
            //StaticVariable.dtExcel = dtFinal.Copy();
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend you to use Bytescout Spreadsheet.

https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html

I tried it with Monodevelop in Unity3D and it is pretty straight forward. Check this sample code to see how the library works:

https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/read-write-excel.html

Comment: Thank you for recommending ByteScout Spreadsheet SDK, glad it works OK for you in Monodevelop in Unity3D! We haven't tried with Unity3D but probably we should now try and add it to the list of source code samples

Comment: You're welcome @EugeneM !
It's always nice to enlarge the list of solutions to have more possibilities to choose.