# MVC Chart Helper From Excel Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, charts

I want to create a chart using MVC Chart Helper where I read the data stored in an Excel spreadsheet.  I know how to create the chart reading the data from a database but I cannot figure out how to do this from an excel file.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, look at this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this by using the chart helper?  The article doesn't mention that.