# How to add using using ExcelTools = Ms.Office?

Tags: c#, excel

I try to read my Excel file and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c) thread
but my problem is that after add `using ExcelTools = Ms.Office;` it says that **The type or namespace name 'Ms' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** although reference `using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` added

Comment: You shouldn't assume that an online code is right by default (not even codes from SO). Also you shouldn't copy codes without understanding what they do exactly (and the line `using ExcelTools = Ms.Office;` is clearly not part of .NET). So... I see two options: either ask the original author (Chris) or just take it as a reference and build your own code (what SO is actually meant to be). PS: if you look for the "Ms.Office" term in this link, you would see that some people have already asked about it (one further tip: in SO comments matter too).

Answer (score 1):

`Ms.Office` namespace is not part of Microsoft Office interop assemblies.

Code in the question you've linked use some custom libraries that implement helper classes/methods in `Ms.Office` namespace. You either need to contact author for sources or remove the line and implement necessary helper functions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the full thread, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c#comment10312768_657211) reply in particular. It clearly states that **Ms** namespace is something that author (Chris) created himself.