# Load an Excel cell value with a leading apostrophe

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetgear

I want to be able to load the exact text within an Excel cell using Spreadsheet gear. This is because I want the leading apostrophe.

For Example the cell has the text;
'Test' This is a test.
Spreadsheet gear strips away the leading '.

```
SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = null;
workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbookSet(Workbooks.Open(excelFileName);
IRange usedRange = workbook.Worksheets[0].UsedRange;
Text = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells[row, 0].Value as string;
```

Is this a limitation of loading data from Excel? Or is there just a different way to load the contents of an Excel cell using Spreadsheet gear?

Comment: I think Chris has already answered this in another [excel question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c). You might be after Value2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of IRange.[Value](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Value.html)/[Text](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Text.html) will not include a leading apostrophe since this is a special case in SpreadsheetGear/Excel that indicates the inputted contents should be force-treated as Text.

One way to get your string value with a leading apostrophe would be to check the IRange.[PrefixCharacter](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~PrefixCharacter.html).  Example:

```
string text = cell.Value.ToString();
if (cell.PrefixCharacter == '\'')
    text = "'" + text;
```

Comment: Also for newbs like me this shows all the properties of the current cell for exploring in VS:  
`SpreadsheetGear.IRange eCell = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells[row, 0];
if (cell.PrefixCharacter == '\'')
text = "'" + text ;`