# Import data from a textbox in excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, import

I have a excel files that contain textboxes and I need to import the data from those boxes. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has actually been addressed on this site before, and rather well. Check it out here: [How to read data of an Excel file using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c)